# Sufficient condition for $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ for it to exists $x$ s.t. $f(x) - g(x) = c$

Tags: functions

I wonder if it is possible to find some conditions on the functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ such that I can be certain that there will exists an x such that $f(x) - g(x) = c$, where $c\in\mathbb{R}$.

I can think in many cases that would satisfy this, but I'm not sure about general conditions. Thank you for your answers :D

Comment: This simplifies, by putting $h = f-g$, to finding when there exists $x$ such that $h(x) = c$.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Although this is a general question, for my specific application I know that x has to be in the interval (0,1) and f(1)=g(1).

Comment: Even better $h(x)=f(x)-g(x)-c$ to finding $x$ such that $h(x)=0$.

Comment: But how can I prove that there will exist an x such that h(x)=0?

Comment: Do you mean $\forall c \in \mathbb{R}, \exists x \in (0,1)$ such that $f(x)-g(x)=c$ or given a particular $c$, how to make sure that $f(x)-g(x)=c$ has a solution in $(0,1)$?

Comment: Siong Thye Goh, the second case. For a given c how can I make sure there exists a solution x such that  $f(x)−g(x)=c$. Knowing that $f(1)=g(1)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, setting $h(x)=f(x)-g(x)-c$, we simplify the task: find $x$ such that $h(x)=0$. Now, it is impossible to say anything unless we put some restrictions on $h$, and there are many possibilities; I'll list a couple.

If we are provided that $h$ is continuous (in particular, if $f$ and $g$ are), then a [theorem by Weierstrass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem) can be used: if $h(a)<0$ and $h(b)>0$ (or vise versa) then there exists $x \in (a,b)$ such that $h(x)=0$.

If we know that $h$ is differentiable, if $h(a)<0$ and $\forall x > a: \,h'(x)>A>0$ (where $A$ is just some positive constant), then, as an application of [mean value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem), there exists $x \in \left(a, a+\frac{-h(a)}{A}\right)$ such that $h(x)=0$.

These criteria can be easily transformed into theorems stating that $\exists x:\,f(x)-g(x)=c$ simply by suиstituting the definition of $h$.

Comment: The theorem by Weierstrass is exactly what would answer my question. Thank you so much!